# Provide WAN access to specific PC within your network

Tags: networking

My current company has a GX80 Meraki Go router.

There is one WAN port to our internet provider and a couple of LAN ports on this device.
We recently had an outside company install a machine that has a built in switch/router on it.

And they are saying that I need to provide a WAN connection to this machine so that their software can VPN into it and they can change parameters from their home office.

If we just provide a LAN connection it doesn't work for them.

How do I go about setting something up to help them out?

Comment: Ask them what ports they need, then setup a port forward on the Meraki router. If they insist that they need a WAN connection, consider finding another company because that's not how things are supposed to work.

Comment: It is done with forwarding. Look it up.

Comment: Depending on what VPN they are using, they might need GRE forwarding to work. This doesn't work on Meraki. On Linux, you could insert the relevant *gre modules, then configure the simple forwarding of port 1723 and the modules would create a related connection for GRE.